# Proper sql table structure with multiple values of a field

Tags: mysql

I have been working with some basic sql databases and am designing an application and am wondering about having multiple values in 1 field.  I am used to a relational DB model and am wondering if sql supports this.  Here is an example delimited record:
PartID: part1
Description: Part Number One
Options: opt1|opt2|opt3
SubOptions: SA1~SA2~SA3|SA2|SA3~SA4

In U2, I would write a record just like this.  In sql, you would have 3 tables witht he following value correct?

Part table:
PartID: part1
Description: Part Number One

Part Options table:
ID: 1
PartID: part1
Option: opt1

ID: 2
PartID: part1
Option: opt2

ID: 3
PartID: part1
Option: opt3

Part Options SubOption table:
ID: 1
PartID: part1
Option: opt1
SubOption: SA1

ID: 2
PartID: part1
Option: opt1
SubOption: SA2

ID: 1
PartID: part1
Option: opt1
SubOption: SA3

....and so on.

I have 2 questions.  Can sql deal with multiple values in 1 field in a record? Basically saving an array in a record or a multi-dimensional array in a record.  Iknow you can write and read on, but can you do selects on elements within the array?

Id what I descripted here the proper way to deal with the sample data structure that I have described?

Thanks in advance for any help.  If there is a good document on this, please provide a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid MySQL do not support multiple attributes in a single column. I suggest you to do that things using N:N relations. There are cases in which also a `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` field with multiple items separated with a string is ok (`"one|two|three"`), if you do not need to use these values to do joins...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multiple value in single field in mysql is called :- [`set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html),
you probably will get disappointed,
the value is not really story in array format

If you are looking for multi-dimensional array,
here is the one :- [XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html)